# Comment Timestamp Wildly Wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, timestamps

The [following comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016337/multiple-security-questions-in-asp-net-membership) just showed up in my activity:

> He may have just phrased that clumsily. The out-of-the-box membership provider will *reset* a password, not *resend* it. I agree that sending the original password would be a security hole.

I probably wrote that -- it sounds like me -- but not recently. But the timestamp on both the question page and [my recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714/craig-stuntz?tab=activity) shows it as three hours ago, when I was asleep.

So I think there's a bug here.

Comment: Maybe you were sleep-commenting.

Comment: Seen this before, was similarly wildly confused before I saw the deleted answer

Comment: A conscious SO user is always awake sheepdogging his comments :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior was a bit confusing so we did make a tweak here.

In the next build, the last activity date (if there is one) or the creation date of the answer will be used when converting it to a comment.  Also, comments on that answer will retain their timestamps when moved (if they're moved at all, this is still a moderator's choice).

Note, this won't retroactively affect previously converted comments, just going forward.

Comment: Possibly you already considered this and decided it was worth it, but if a post and its associated comments get converted into comments on another thread that already has comments around the same time, the two threads will get intermingled and probably make no sense

Comment: @Michael - Indeed! This can possibly some of the time, often though that (what was an answer) wasn't relative to the comment stream anyway.  Also, *by default* we don't convert the comments, that's rather rare, so hopefully that's not the case often.  The alternative is a confusing out of place comment (or comments) potentially years after the question (or other answer...whatever it goes with) that makes even less sense.

Answer (score 5):

A moderator converted Malfist's answer and all its comments to comments on the question.  Whenever we move answers and comments this way, they get a new timestamp.

Comment: That makes sense to me as a programmer. As a site user, it's surprising.

Comment: @Craig: I agree.  It would be better if the original timestamp was retained.

Comment: I used to think that, but if a post and its associated comments get converted into comments on another thread that already has comments around the same time, the two threads get intermingled and it makes no sense

Comment: @Michael: Ah, I hadn't thought of that.  I guess it is better to give them new timestamps so that group stays together in the comment thread.